# firebase real time database returns error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

This is the code for an app I am making. Basically, it shows all the user's locations on a map with the phone number they used to log in on the marker. For some reason, an error is coming up that says Cannot read property '0' of undefined. This is the line of code it's referring to. My coordinates show up in the real-time database so I don't know why it's throwing this error.  I also included a screenshot of the console that tells the error.

[picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rljeq.png)

```
  lat: data.User.l[0],
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Place this inside the HTML head; don't use async defer for now -->

    
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/geofire/4.1.2/geofire.min.js"></script>

  <script>
        
        var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "carrier-35d7c.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://carrier-35d7c.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "carrier-35d7c",
    storageBucket: "carrier-35d7c.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "827792028763"
  };
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
        }
        
        //Create a node at firebase location to add locations as child keys
        //var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
        
        // Create a new GeoFire key under users Firebase location
        //var geoFire = new GeoFire(locationsRef.push());
        //Create a node at firebase location to add locations as child keys
        //confirm(firebase.auth().currentUser)
    
    //var a = localStorage.getItem('phoneNumber');
    
 
        var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
        var pushRef = locationsRef.push()
        var postID = pushRef.key;
      console.log(postID);
      
      // Create a new GeoFire key under users Firebase location
      // replace var geoFire = new GeoFire(locationsRef.push()); with
      var geoFire = new GeoFire(pushRef); 
      </script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      
    
      // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
      // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
      // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
      // locate you.
      var map, infoWindow;
      var lat, lng;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 18
          //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lng = position.coords.longitude;
            
            var pos = {lat: lat, lng: lng, name };
                _setGeoFire();
              var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
locationsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val();
 
   
   
  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: data.User.l[0],
      lng: data.User.l[1]
     
    },
    map: map,
     
      
   // new google.maps.Size(42, 68)
  });
 a = localStorage.getItem('phone')
  
  var database = firebase.database();
              var fruitsRef = database.ref('locations/'+ postID + '/User/g');
              fruitsRef.update ({
                number: (a)
              })
            
  
  marker.addListener('click', (function(data) {
    return function(e) {
      infoWindow.setContent(this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>" + data.User.g.number);
      infoWindow.open(map, this);
    }
  }(data)));
  
});
          
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Current Location');
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }
      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
     function _setGeoFire(){
geoFire.set("User", [lat, lng] ).then(()=>{
  console.log("Location added");
  
  pushRef.child("User").onDisconnect().remove();
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
}
    </script>
    <script 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD2nPlSt_nM7PSKD8So8anbUbBYICFWcCA&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```